# Location replaced while running makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

Code snippets of makefile:

```
ERROR_PARSER_YACC = $(SRCDIR)/ermparseyac.y
ERROR_PARSER_LEX  = $(SRCDIR)/ermparselex.l

ERM_OBJS = \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermparseyac.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermparselex.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermclient.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermcommit.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/erminit.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermlog.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermmcp.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermsyslog.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermparse.o \
    $(OBJDIR)/ermreport.o

$(ERM_OBJS):    $(SRCDIR)/$(@F:.o=.c)
                @echo .... Compiling $(@:.o=.c)
                $(IDA_CC) $(SRCDIR)/$(@F:.o=.c) -o $@
```

The value of SRCDIR is `"/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src".`

When I run the makefile, I get the following error:

```
.... Compiling /home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/obj/ermparselex.c
cc  -g                         -DANSI -DORA817 -DTRACE_ON -DIDA_VERSION='"ISP-RG-V5.10.7GEN2A"' -DNO_MCP -DBUILDING_ERP  -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/include -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/module_test  -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/include  -I/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/cfm/include    -c /home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src/ermparselex.c -o /home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/obj/ermparselex.o

/pf24/wholesale/dvp/comps/erm/src/ermparselex.l:282: error: static declaration of âget_comment_lineâ follows non-static declaration
/pf24/wholesale/dvp/comps/erm/src/ermparselex.l:168: error: previous implicit declaration of âget_comment_lineâ was here
```

I don't understand how makefile is replacing the location "/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src" to a different location "/pf24/wholesale/dvp/comps/erm/src/" which is not present in the sever.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing make output with your compiler output. The error messages you showed are not produced by make, but by whatever compiler (probably gcc) you're using.

Note that the assignemt to `ERROR_PARSER_LEX` is a deffered assignment. The value of `SRCDIR` is expanded whenever `ERROR_PARSER_LEX` is used. That might explain why the value of `SRCDIR` doesn't appear to be what you think it should be.

**Edit**

The problem doesn't appear to be related to your makefile. Make clearly shows that it's passed  `/home/wholesale/children/dev5/comps/erm/src/ermparselex.c` to the compiler as source file.

The error message which points to a different file probably means that some source file is including something from /pf24.

The `-E` option of gcc can be quite useful in diagnosing such issues. Replace the `-o ...` options by it, and it'll output the preprocessed source code to stdout. This should show you which file is including the file in /pf24.

Comment: Hi Kristof, thanks for the response. Now that I know how to solve the error "error: static declaration of âget_comment_lineâ follows non-static declaration", I modify "ermparselex.l" in the path "/home/dev5/comps/erm/src". But the code modification deos not reflect when I run the makefile again.

Comment: Please post your makefile, so we can figure out why it's using a different source file from the one you expect.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant makefile snippet(s). Don't just post it as a comment, it'll be unreadable.

Comment: For "lex" command to work, I installed the flex and bison packages of Gnu.

Comment: Make should be showing you the actual lex command it's using. Is it running 'lex /home/dev5/comps/erm/src/ermparselex.l' or something else? (Please post more extensive bits of the makefile. You're almost certainly not giving us enough information to help you.)

Comment: Hi Kristof, as requested, I have modified my question with the contents of makefile.